# Javascript: update dropdown when user is changing values manually

Tags: jquery, dropdown

as a reference to my project: https://koppenleitner.de/print/

Below the label "Ausgabeformat" you can see a dropdown menu. There are preselected formats to choose from but I want to change the dropdown element to "Eigener Wert" when somebody is changing the values in "Breite" and "Höhe". How can i achieve this.

```html
    <label for="formatInput">Ausgabeformat</label>
    <form action="/revenue_lines/lock" id="outGroup" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
      </div>
      <select name="formatInput" class="form-group" id="formatInput">
        <option value="210_297">Eigener Wert</option>
        <option value="210_297">DIN A4 Hochformat</option>
        <option value="297_420">DIN A3 Hochformat</option>
        <option value="420_594">DIN A2 Hochformat</option>
        <option value="594_841">DIN A1 Hochformat</option>
        <option value="841_1189">DIN A0 Hochformat</option>
        <option value="297_210">DIN A4 Querformat</option>
        <option value="420_297">DIN A3 Querformat</option>
        <option value="594_420">DIN A2 Querformat</option>
        <option value="841_594">DIN A1 Querformat</option>
        <option value="1189_841">DIN A0 Querformat</option>
      </select></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="widthGroup">
    <label for="widthInput">Breite</label>
    <input name="width" class="form-control" type="text" id="widthInput">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="heightGroup">
    <label for="heightInput">Höhe</label>
    <input name="heigth" class="form-control" type="text" id="heightInput">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery code to update the textfields when something is preselected with the dropdown menu:

```
  <script>
    $('#formatInput').on('change', function () {
      var val = this.value;
      var parts = val.split("_");
      $('#widthInput').val(parts[0]);
      $('#heightInput').val(parts[1]);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$('#widthInput , #heightInput').change(function(){
    $('#formatInput').val('210_297');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If dropdown values are fixed then you can do as below:

```
$('#widthInput').on('change', function() {
$('#formatInput').val('210_297');
});

$('#heightInput').on('change', function() {
$('#formatInput').val('210_297');
});
```

Or you can do combine as well:

```
$('#widthInput, #heightInput').on('change', function() {
$('#formatInput').val('210_297');
});
```

Or else if the option sequence is also fixed then you can do to select first option of the dropdown:

```
$('#widthInput, #heightInput').on('change', function() {
$("#formatInput").val($("#formatInput option:first").val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It kinda works. I changed the preselected value of "Eigener Wert" to "0_0" and placed your code at the end of the html. If the user is inserting own values the dropdown changes to "eigener Wert" (translated to "own value"). The weird thing is right now: if you refresh the page, the values of "Breite" and "Höhe" go up.